# How can I whitelist P2P connections?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online, networking

According to [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/GrandTheftAutoV_PC/comments/345joh/), GTA Online uses a P2P (Peer-to-Peer) network instead of actual servers on their end. This is obviously very cheap and allows for hacking, which is fairly common especially on the PC version. A solution are invite-only sessions or friend-only sessions, but they have the disadvantage that you cannot do the CEO missions from the "Further Adventures in Finance and Felony" DLC.

Is there a way I can whitelist certain IPs in this P2P-network, so that I can create a "Public" Freeroam Lobby with only my friends? Any pointers to special software or exploitable network internals would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I used to have something called [Netlimiter](https://www.netlimiter.com/). Basically it allows you to rate limit, disconnect, reconnect, any connection incoming on your PC. If your friends were to give you their IPs, you could practically kick any player that joins the session, by disconnecting their IPs. I'm sure there's a way for you to whitelist connections also, and Netlimiter will deny access of any other connections incoming through GTA 5.